# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0

Tags: android, react-native, android-sdk-tools

I checked and updated my android SDK (also react-native-image-crop-picker), but I couldn't find the version of support 27.+ all the time.

below are more information

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
-------------------------------------------------------
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.

A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-image-crop-picker'.

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-image-crop-picker:_debugPublishCopy'.

Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0.
Searched in the following locations:
           
file:/D:/AndroidSDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.0/appcompat-v7-27.1.0.pom
               
file:/D:/AndroidSDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.0/appcompat-v7-27.1.0.jar
               
file:/C:/Users/***/Desktop/LastDesign/InsurAgentApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.0/appcompat-v7-27.1.0.jar
           
Required by:
InsurAgentApp:react-native-image-crop-picker:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.54.2
Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0.
Searched in the following locations:
               
file:/D:/AndroidSDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.0/appcompat-v7-27.1.0.pom
               
file:/D:/AndroidSDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.0/appcompat-v7-27.1.0.jar
file:/C:/Users/***/Desktop/LastDesign/InsurAgentApp/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.0/appcompat-v7-27.1.0.jar
Required by:
InsurAgentApp:react-native-image-crop-picker:unspecified > com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

---

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
  }

  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }

}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
  compile 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native'
  compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

}
```

Comment: post your gradle file.

Comment: you have to add the google maven repo

Comment: Please provide your build.gradle (Project: ) as well.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Gradle is looking for the specified libraries in your local storage.
Try [adding the Google's Maven repository](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven) to your top-level **build.gradle** file.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have offline work on.

Go to:

File > Settings > write "offline" on the search bar > under Gradle, see if Offline Work is checked. If so, uncheck it.